# UIScrollView subclass trigger event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've tried for some days understand Xcode Subclasses and Categories - and after all I found one event that are fired.

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    NSLog(@"foo");
}
```

And for more confusion, after read  [Apple iOS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a) I get this stuff:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"bar");
}
```

First event are fired, but from Apple documentation are not. Why?!

But in the first case, although he was fired the UIScrollView loses their scroll/drag'n' bounce behavior. I think it's because after overrride `setContentOffset` I would need to call the parent method to keep the default behavior of the UIScrollView. But I'm already exhausted from test obsolete Xcode approaches.

Than why second code are not fired and how call parent overridden method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Subclassing the scroll view is unlikely to be the approach you should take.

Comment: @Wain I'm trying to understand Pull To Refresh. It's for knowledge purposes... But basically I can create this behavior from scratch.

Comment: What do you want to understand about it? If you wanted to implement pull to refresh manually you should still use the scroll view delegate `scrollViewDidScroll` (or observe the `contentOffset`) and `contentInset`.

Comment: I've tried - `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { NSLog(@"fooooobar"); }` but it never fired

Comment: did you add the instance as the delegate?

Comment: @Wain, honestly the concept from delegate still means exoteric to me - I'm using Storyboard in my project, and tried to click with CTRL and link with all the possible options (With the UIView, and the ViewController), but nothing change. Can you recommend a piece of documentation, a tutorial or give me a starting point?

Comment: Start with: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: @Wain I am really thankfully for your recommendation, this paper clarified almost all cocoa puzzles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the super (:parent) here

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    NSLog(@"foo  New Offset x: %.0f y: %.0f", contentOffset.x, contentOffset.y);
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}
```

And, for the second one; That is not a delegate method (:event), this is a method provided to developer actually, to initiate scrolling to a specific offset with/without animation. You probably do not need to override this.

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Even more; even the first one is not an event, that's a message sent to scrollview to change the offset, but you can get in between and do your thing using that as an event trigger, and call super again to let it do it's work.

If you want to get real events on scrollView, you need to set up a delegate as documented here;
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate

And I also agree with Wain on sharing this link,
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: As I said before, I am very grateful to the help given from @Wain and now your answer fits as a glove. After I read and implemented the delegate in my CustomClass all works like a charm - I was without a starting point and really did not know where to start. Thank you.